# How to addEventListener and function with element as a parameter to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom-events

My goal is to have a bunch of div with clickable words to pass their ids to a Javascript function when one of them is clicked by the user. It works flawlessly for

```
    <div id="wordbox">
        <div id="pd"><h4>pdf</h4><br></div>
        <div id="an"><h3>analysis</h3></div>
        <div id="ai"><h2>artificial intelligence</h2></div>
        <div id="tr"><h4>trends</h4><br><br></div>
        <div id="dm"><h3>data mining</a></div>
    </div>
```

```
 var word = document.getElementById("pd");
 word.addEventListener("click", function(){ showSlide(word.id) });
```

but I don't manage to get it working for all elements. This fails:

```
  var wb = document.getElementById("wordbox").children;

  wb.forEach(function (element, index){
    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
      showSlide(element.id);
    });
  });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wb` is not a real array, it is an array-like object called live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children). You can get an array using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). You can also use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the elements

```js
var wb = document.querySelectorAll("#wordbox > div");
// new browsers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#bcd:api.NodeList.forEach
// wb
// To support older browsers
Array.from(wb)
  .forEach(function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(element.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="wordbox">
  <div id="pd">
    <h4>pdf</h4><br></div>
  <div id="an">
    <h3>analysis</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="ai">
    <h2>artificial intelligence</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="tr">
    <h4>trends</h4><br><br></div>
  <div id="dm">
    <h3>data mining</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelecorAll() returns NodeList and NodeList has forEach() method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach so why we need to convert it to array ?

Comment: @missKK Looks like I'm not upto date with the recent API changes

Answer (score 2):

When you select the children from a node, it actually returns an `array-like collection` which is *similar* but not quite an `array`. In order to use `forEach` you first need to convert it into an `array`, and in the case below, I used the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert it into an `array` that allows me to use `forEach`.

```js
const wb = document.querySelector('#wordbox')
const children = [...wb.children]

children.forEach(child => {
  child.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(child.id)
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="wordbox">
    <div id="pd"><h4>pdf</h4><br></div>
    <div id="an"><h3>analysis</h3></div>
    <div id="ai"><h2>artificial intelligence</h2></div>
    <div id="tr"><h4>trends</h4><br><br></div>
    <div id="dm"><h3>data mining</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I will read about that spread syntax. Too bad I can only accept one answer.